# Easy desktop icons

Tags: shortcuts

I would like an easy way to have most of my programmes,like chrome,firefox,emapthy,rythmnbox  - on the desktop.
I am running 13.10 with Gnome 3 and have not found an easy solution.

Please is there an easy solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Creating shortcut links to launch applications:

Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and copy the target applications `*.desktop` file to your `Desktop`. e.g. for VLC Media Player the `*.desktop` the command would be:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop ~/Desktop
```

Now make the copy on the desktop executable with using `chmod`. e.g.: for `vlc.desktop` it would be

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/vlc.desktop
```

And then you should be able to launch the application by double clicking the icon on the desktop.

---

#### Searching the `*.desktop` file for the application:

If you need to make a little search for the proper `*.desktop` file for the target application using some related keywords (e.g. for `vlc` it could be *vlc*, *media player* or others), here's some codes that should help.

1. Direct search for the keyword in the filename:

   ```
   ls /usr/share/applications/*your_app_keyword*.desktop
   ```

   so if you're looking for `vlc`, it would be:

   ```
   ls /usr/share/applications/*vlc*.desktop
   ```
2. Searching the files contents to see if the keyword is there:

   For this, you can copy the entire line of codes below (select entire line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and paste it in the terminal using the shortcut key combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> make changes to fit your context like you can replace the `/usr/share/applications` with the path where you want to look in and here I've used *"media player"* as the keyword which you should replace with that of your choice and hit enter. (Also remember to use the double quotes if you're using white spaces in your keyword.)

   ```
   for i in $( ls -R /usr/share/applications/*.desktop); do if grep -i "media player" "$i" > /dev/null; then echo "$i"; fi; done;
   ```

These should output some `*.desktop` file. See if they're the one you are searching for. If yes, that's your target `*.desktop` file to be used to create the application launch link as explained above.

---

#### An example with demonstrating the complete process:

The command:

```
$ for i in $( ls -R /usr/share/applications/*.desktop); \
  do if grep -i "rhythmbox" "$i" > /dev/null; then echo "$i"; \
  fi; done;
```

outputs these:

```
/usr/share/applications/rhythmbox.desktop
/usr/share/applications/rhythmbox-device.desktop
```

and among these, `/usr/share/applications/rhythmbox.desktop` starts the application's UI. So now we'll use this path to create a desktop launch icon.

To copy the file to your desktop, use:

```
$ cp /usr/share/applications/rhythmbox.desktop ~/Desktop
```

Then you'll have to make it executable with this:

```
$ chmod +x ~/Desktop/rhythmbox.desktop
```

Similarly, you have the other on your desktop.

Comment: How would I find the path to a `.desktop` file for a particular application? E.g.: The file for VLC is `vlc.desktop`, not `VLC Media Player.desktop`

Comment: yeah.. you `cat` the `*.desktop` files to check..

Comment: That should be explained in your answer. Maybe `grep -R 'Name=.*Ubuntu.*' '/usr/share/applications' "$HOME/.local/share/applications"`? Replace `Ubuntu` with the program name,

Comment: These commands work, but i have a headache now. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Cam, ..is it the commands! ..you should try what aditya [suggests](http://askubuntu.com/a/410413/212123) ..quick and simple.

Comment: Dragging and dropping does not work from the user folder or anywhere else, full stop guys.

Answer (score 2):

### For a single icon at a time:

1. Open the Dash by pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (aka   <kbd>[image: WindowsKey]</kbd>   key in Windows keyboard),
2. Search for the application you want on desktop,
3. Drag and drop the app icon on your desktop.

   Here are the snapshots:

[image: snapa1]
[image: snapa2]

### For multiple icons at a time:

1. Open Nautilus or other file manager and browse to the directory `/usr/share/applications`. (Or in the Nautilus window, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) and type in the path/location: `/usr/share/location/` and hit enter as shown in the snapshot.)
   [image: snapb1]
2. Select the application icon of the those which you want to copy (to select multiple, press-hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click the icons), and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy, and go to the desktop where you'd paste them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. Or with all desired icons selected, right-click on any selected icon and from the context menu select *Copy to -> Desktop*.
   [image: snapb2]

Comment: drag and drop.. quick and easy.. nice... didn't know we could do that.. +1

Comment: accept the answer if it suits you,it helps me to be more reputed and tells everybody that the question is solved.

Comment: None of the above works. Ububtu sucy with Gnome 3 - i cannot drag and drop

Comment: have you tried the other option,it will surely work on any distro and any version.Also explain in your question why drag and drop doesn't work.

Comment: Drag and drop does not work.

Comment: Why don't you copy files from usr/share/applications?

Comment: @RegisteredUser When I try and drag and drop on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit I get this error message in a dialog box : "Error while copying. There was an error getting information about "/". > Show more details  The specified location is not supported. "

Comment: @Scooter what are you trying to bring in dash?

Comment: @RegisteredUser I am tying to drag an application, say LibreWriter, over to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can run these commands:

```
search='VLC'
grep -Ri "Name=.*$search.*" '/usr/share/applications' "$HOME/.local/share/applications"
```

replace `VLC` with the program you want to add to the desktop (leave the quotes).

> Example output:
>
> ```
> $ search='Ubuntu'
> $ grep -Ri 'Name=.*$search.*' '/usr/share/applications' "$HOME/.local/share/applications"
> /usr/share/applications/ubuntuone-control-panel-qt-gnome.desktop:Name=Ubuntu One
> /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-software-center.desktop:Name=Ubuntu Software Center
> /usr/share/applications/UbuntuOneMusiconeubuntucom.desktop:Name=Ubuntu One Music
> /usr/share/applications/ubuntuone-installer.desktop:Name=Ubuntu One
> ```

You can then run

```
cp -v /path/to/file "$HOME/Desktop/"
```

Replacing `/path/to/file` with the value in purple of the program you'd like from the above commands.

Comment: Could you guys perhaps give me the commands for chrome firefox rythmnbox and steam?

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as dragging an icon from the dash to the Desktop. But unfortunately we have to use the terminal.

You must install the following package.

sudo apt-get install gnome-panel

Then just run the command:

gnome-desktop-item-edit Desktop --create-new

[image]

In the example I'm creating a shortcut for firefox. My interface is in Portuguese but I think you can understand the example.